# Wallet JSON file - field "secret" purpose

Tags: wallets

I downloaded a wallet JSON file from the tezos alphanet [faucet](https://faucet.tzalpha.net/).

What is the field "secret" used for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alphanet is initialized with a set of account similar to the ones present in the mainnet genesis block. The faucet distribute those accounts on demand. This secret proves that you are the real owner of the account. This is used to forge the activation operation.